# Only my phone cannot connect to only one specific WiFi

Tags: wi-fi

I've seen plenty of problems where people's phones can't detect any WiFi networks, or if a particular router can't connect with mobiles, but I don't have any of those problems. My problem is very specific: My office WiFi is not visible on my phones WiFi list, but everyone else's phones can connect just fine. However, my phone can connect to every other WiFi with no problem. In fact, every other WiFi (21 of them) on my laptops list is also visible on my phone. It is *only* my office WiFi which is not visible. This happened after a WiFi upgrade a few months ago. Does anyone have any idea what could be causing this?

Android version: 6.0

Phone: Moto G 2nd generation

Comment: Is the office AP you're trying to connect to a 5g? There are some wireless modules that are unable to detect certain frequencies.

Comment: What country do you live in? There are Wifi channels which are not allowed to be used in certain countries. Therefore make sure the Android Wifi country settings are correct.

Comment: "5g" is the name of the next generation mobile network standard. I assume you mean 5GHz.

Comment: I do mean 5GHz.  I was assuming that the Access Point OP was trying to access had a _5G suffix.

Answer (score 0):

This happens quite a few times. According to my observations. I have noticed the main reason behind this is entering a wrong key (password) to the wifi network which makes it temporarily disabled from the wifi list of the phone. Try forgetting the network which you may have connected once and reconnect to the same network with correct password.